# Using a loop to add a new point to a figure at each constant rate

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot figures that have a point inside it. I want to add a new point to the figure at each `10` steps (or any constant rate).For example, if I have `50` steps then I should have `50` figures. Figures from `1` to `10` will have one point, figures from `11` to `20` will have two points, and figures from `21` to `30` will have three points, and so on. I did that in the below code  but, unfortunately, it gave me only one point for all figures.

```
clc;
clear;
Current_Path=pwd;
cd (Current_Path)
mkdir('Photos','part1')
pridir = 'Photos\part';
R=rand(1,50);
Y=rand(1,50);
for i=1:50
    figure
    for jj = 1:floor((i-1)/10)+1
        if jj<=1
            plot (R(i),Y(i),'*r');
            printto = sprintf('%s%d\\Motion%03d',pridir,1,i);
            print('-djpeg90',printto)
            close(gcf);
            hold on
        else
            R(i)=R(i-((jj-1)*10));
            Y(i)=Y(i-((jj-1)*10));
            plot (R(i),Y(i),'*r');
            printto = sprintf('%s%d\\Motion%03d',pridir,1,i);
            print('-djpeg90',printto)
            close(gcf);
            hold on
        end
    end
    hold off
end
```

Comment: also use `drawnow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two mains problems:

- You're closing the figure after each plot. Move the `close(clf)` to the location your `hold off` currently is to avoid closing the figure after each plotted point.
- You `pridir` call is missing a `1` in the `part1`, which causes MATLAB to not save the figure since there is no directory `part`.

To prettify you could make a couple of additional changes. `hold on` holds a figure until you call `hold off`. In your case you can omit the `hold off` completely, as you close the figure after the loops. Also, consider using `ii` as a variable (just as your `jj`) since [`i` is the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Updated code

```
Current_Path=pwd;
cd (Current_Path)
mkdir('Photos','part1')
pridir = 'Photos\part1'; % change to 'part1'
R=rand(1,50);
Y=rand(1,50);
for ii=1:50 % change to ii
    figure
    hold on % move hold on here
    for jj = 1:floor((ii-1)/10)+1
        if jj<=1
            plot (R(ii),Y(ii),'*r'); % remove close(gcf) and print calls
        else
            R(ii)=R(ii-((jj-1)*10));
            Y(ii)=Y(ii-((jj-1)*10));
            plot (R(ii),Y(ii),'*r'); % remove close and print 
        end
    end
    printto = sprintf('%s%d\\Motion%03d',pridir,1,ii); 
    print('-djpeg90',printto) % move print outside the inner loop
    close(gcf); % finally close the figure after saving
end
```